# How to create custom writer for Spark Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

How can I create a custom write format for Spark Dataframe to use it like `df.write.format("com.mycompany.mydb").save()`? I've tried reading through Datastax Cassandra connector code but still couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark 3.0 completely changes the API. Some new interfaces e.g. [TableProvider](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/connector/catalog/TableProvider.html) and [SupportsWrite](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/connector/catalog/SupportsWrite.html) have been added.

You might find [this guide](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/easy-guide-to-create-a-write-data-source-in-apache-spark-3-f7d1e5a93bdb) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Using Spark's [DataSourceV2](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/DataSourceV2.html).

If your are using Spark version < 2.3, then you can use Spark Data Source API V1.